# Знания для Java Junior

Tags: java

Есть ряд компаний которые занимаются разработкой мобильных приложений. В основном это интернет-магазины, приложения-каталоги и прочие приложения для бизнеса. Есть вариант туда устроится через n-ное время, но возник вопрос. Чтобы не порождать дискуссии и разные мнения хотелось бы узнать необходимый минимум для разработки такого приложения и какими инструментами пользуются программисты.

Думаю он(минимум) не такой разносторонний. Гугление дает слишком расплывчатый ответ.

Нужно ли знать Hibernate, Android Studio, сервлеты/апплеты и т.д.
Если накидаете список что по Вашему мнению необходимо буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Любой будущий программист должен уметь нагуглить FAQ вопросы** (включая вопрос "Знания для Java Junior", естественно).

1. Типы в `Java`, `inboxing`, `outboxing`, как примитивы друг в друга преобразуются.
2. Коллекции, иерархия интерфейсов и реализаций, чем `ArrayList` «лучше» `LinkedList`. Обязательный вопрос по `HashMap`-ам, что такое хеш-функция, внутреннее устройство.
3. Строки, циклы, управляющие структуры, что появилось в `JDK 7` по сравнению с 6-й. На 8-ку еще мало кто перешел.
4. Интерфейс, Абстрактный класс, 3 принципа ООП, несколько шаблонов проектирования.
5. `Servlet`, `JSP`, `JSTL`, `Tomcat` или другой `Servlet container`, никуда не девается жизненный цикл и как это все работает.
6. Advanced топики для джуна: системы контроля версий `Git`, `Svn`, системы сборок `Maven`, `Gradle`, `Spring`, `Hibernate`, `Web-Service`-ы (обычно `REST`) - жирный плюс.
7. Иногда чтобы завалить спрашивают про устройство памяти, что такое стек или куча, куда создаются объекты, зачем нужен `garbage collection`, параметры запуска `JVM`.
8. Базовый `SQL`, подзапросы, что такое сущность->связь, спроектировать 2 таблички и выполнить по ним запросы. `noSQL` могут спросить.
9. Базовый `JS` и `CSS`. `HTML`. Основные типы HTTP запросов, в чем их предназначение и отличие.
10. `JDBC`, как это вручную создать `connection`, запихать `statement`, `preparedstatement`, вычитать данные в `result-set`, пробежаться по нему, закрыть `connection`.
11. Как работает `wait`, `notify`, `notify` `all`, почему нельзя использовать `sleep`, как создать `dead-lock`, вокруг чего бывает синхронизация.
12. Что такое `static`-методы и переменные.
13. Потоки ввода вывода, базовые вещи, прочитать строку из консоли, какие бывают фильтры.
14. Английский крайне важен для аутсорса.

[Источник](https://dou.ua/forums/topic/12167/#618964)

Comment: не уверен что джуну нужны сервлеты, jsp, jstl и пр, и вообще не уверен, что  кому то они сейчас нужны. JS спорный пункт, можно легко без него обойтись java разработчику.

Comment: эти требования подойдут для мдла тоже.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor все, что подходит для миддла автоматически подходит для джуна, не так ли?

Comment: 1. По-моему, это называется boxing/unboxing (+autoboxing, для неявных). 5-10 это уровень настолько сильного джуна, что аж мидла, причём направленного на веб. Нет, не всё подходящее мидлу априори годится и для джуна, у джуна потолок сложности заметно ниже. Конечно, знать всё это полезно, но это не "необходимый минимум".

Comment: Про 7 и 11 спрашивают на сеньорских собесах ) Тюнинг JVM это не то, что может знать джун.